# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver WebappClassLoader

Tags: mysql, tomcat5.5

I am creating a Webservice from JAVA EE version, with Java code which calls MySQL database and get/put results from database.

Webservice running fine but it doesn't connect to Database:

> Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

*edited after previous problem got resolved*

Comment: can you tell us the version of Tomcat and JDK that you are using ?

Comment: Tomcat Version 5.5 JDK 1.7

Comment: the exception now that you are getting is due to the older version of the Tomcat  , try upgrading to Tomcat8 or Tomcat7 it will work. Tomcat 5.5 is not compatible with jdk1.7

Answer (score 0):

you need use mysql.jar in classpath.

Comment: How do you do that? What makes you think that OP hasn't already done that?

Comment: i added mySQL.jar in Tomcat files now

Comment: Adding files I am not getting Class not found error now.
I am getting below error now.

Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException